Overkill definition of finite and infinte sums in $\mathbb{R}$
Normally, one defines for $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and given $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$ for each $m\leq k \leq n$ the finite sum as $$\sum_{k=m}^n a_k:= \begin{cases} a_m+\dots +a_n &, n\geq m\\ 0 &, n<m \end{cases}.$$ And for a given sequence $(a_k)_{k \geq m}$ we define an infinte sum as the sequence $(s_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of the partial sums $s_n:= \sum_{k=m}^n a_k$ and write $s= \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} a_k$ if $(s_n)$ converges to $s$.
The suggestion through the dots $\, + ... + \,$, however, does not provide a rigorous definition. To overcome that issue one uses the recursion principle:

Theorem: Let $X$ be an arbitrary nonempty set and $x \in X$. We futhermore assume that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a function $h_n:X^n \to X$. Then there exists a unique function $f:\mathbb{N} \to X$ with $f(0)=x$ and $f(n+1)=h_{n+1}(f(0),\dots,f(n))$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm not sure but I think a rigorous definition is now be given by:

Definition: Let $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a real sequence. Then the finite sum of $(a_k)$ from $m$ to $n$ is defined by
$$\sum_{k=m}^{n}a_k:= \begin{cases} f(n), & \text{for } n\geq m \\ 0, & \text{for } n<m\end{cases},$$
where $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the unique function from the recursion theorem defined by $f(0)= \begin{cases} a_m, & \text{if } m=0 \\ 0, & \text{if } m>0\end{cases}$ and $f(k+1)=\begin{cases} f(k)+a_{k+1}, & \text{if } k+1\geq m \\ 0, & \text{else } \end{cases}$.

By induction one can easily show that the value of the finite sum only depends from the values $a_m, \dots, a_n$ of the sequence $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. Hence, if we don't have a complete sequence $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, i.e. just $(a_k)_{k \geq m}$ or $(a_k)_{k=m}^n$, we can define the finite sum from this incomplete sequence as the finite sum of the sequence $(\tilde{a}_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\tilde{a}_k :=\begin{cases} a_k &, m \leq k \leq n\\ \text{arbitrary value in } \mathbb{R} &, \text{else} \end{cases}$.
From that definition of a finite sum one can define an infinte sum for a sequence $(a_k)_{k\geq m}$ as above as the the sequence  $(s_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of the partial sums $s_n:= \sum_{k=m}^n a_k$. Note that $s_n=0$ for $n<m$ and that $(a_k)_{k \geq m}$ can again be extended to a sequence $(\tilde{a}_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$.
Is this the right rigorous definition? Is there any advantage in defining the the infinite sum by $(s_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $s_n= \sum_{k=0}^{n-m} a_{k+m}$ instead of letting the first $m$ sums be $0$? (I know that it doesn't matter for the convergence). What do we exactly write in the definition of a finite sum if $n <m$ and we have an empty sequence?

You can define finite sums recursively.  $\sum_{k=m}^ma_k=a_m$ and then $\sum_{k=m}^na_k=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}a_k +a_n$ for $n>m$.

I believe that the most natural way to define sums is to use recursion and sets, i.e., for any finite set $A$
$$
\sum_{a \in A} f(a) = \begin{cases} f(x) + \displaystyle\sum_{a \in A \setminus {x}} f(a), \text{ if } x \in A \\
0, \text{ if } A = \varnothing.
\end{cases}
$$
And you just need to prove the order in which the $x$'s are taken doesn't matter (or define the sum by taking $x$ to be the lowest term, and then show that all orders lead to the same result).
The case of the empty set is justified by the wish to have the following property hold, even if one of the sets is empty
If $A \cap B = \varnothing$, then
$$
\sum_{a\in A} f(a) + \sum_{b\in B}f(b)
 = \sum_{c\in A\cup B} f(c).
$$
Then integer bounded sums can be defined by
$$
\sum_{k=m}^n f(k) := \sum_{k \in [\mkern-3mu[m, n]\mkern-3mu]} f(k),
$$
with
$$
[\mkern-3mu[m, n]\mkern-3mu] := \{ x \in \mathbb N \ |\ m \leq x \leq n \}.
$$
And if $n < m$ then $[\mkern-3mu[m, n]\mkern-3mu] = \varnothing$.
Note that everything could work with multiplication, maximum/minimum or even union/intersection. The only condition on the binary operator is that it has to be commutative, associative and has to have a neutral element to replace the "$0$".
